# Batch script delete folder task output result

Tags: batch-file

I want to see the output task result of the following batch script. i am not quite sure how can I see the result.

i tried `-vv` but script gave the output that system could not find the folder which is valid though because the folder is already deleted.

`@RD /S /Q "N:\test"`

Answer (score 0):

What result are you expecting? You ask it it to delete a folder and it does that, so no result means it is done the task successfully. There can be only 2 outcomes here, either it cannot be deleted (locked/nonexistent etc.) or it is removed (no message needed).

`rd` or `rmdir` does not show any results if successful.
You can however create your own custom messages, which are 100% accurate.

```
@RD /S /Q "N:\test" >nul 2>&1 && echo Folder successfully removed || echo Failed to remove folder
```

or to be more specific on the folder that was removed in the message:

```
set "folder=N:\test"
@RD /S /Q "%folder%" >nul 2>&1 && echo %folder% successfully removed || echo Failed to remove %folder%
```

or a list of folders using a `for` loop:

```
@echo off
set "folders="N:\test" "E:\test 1" "x:\Another Test""
for %%i in (%folders%) do rd /S /Q "%%~i" >nul 2>&1 && echo "%%~i" successfully removed || echo Failed to remove "%%~i"
```